# Error on running JACOB example

Tags: java, jacob

I'm working on excel using `jacob` library. I'm trying to interact with excel with basic operation. I'm executing below code and getting an error. What should I do?

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstance(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstance(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java)
    at DispatchTest.main(DispatchTest.java:7)`

```
public class DispatchTest {
     public static void main(String[] args)
      {

        ActiveXComponent xl = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");
        Object xlo = xl.getObject();
        try {
          System.out.println("version="+xl.getProperty("Version"));
          System.out.println("version="+Dispatch.get(xlo, "Version"));
          xl.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(true));
          Object workbooks = xl.getProperty("Workbooks").toDispatch();
          Object workbook = Dispatch.get(workbooks,"Add").toDispatch();
          Object sheet = Dispatch.get(workbook,"ActiveSheet").toDispatch();
          Object a1 = Dispatch.invoke(sheet, "Range", Dispatch.Get,
                                      new Object[] {"A1"},
                                      new int[1]).toDispatch();
          Object a2 = Dispatch.invoke(sheet, "Range", Dispatch.Get,
                                      new Object[] {"A2"},
                                      new int[1]).toDispatch();
          Dispatch.put(a1, "Value", "123.456");
          Dispatch.put(a2, "Formula", "=A1*2");
          System.out.println("a1 from excel:"+Dispatch.get(a1, "Value"));
          System.out.println("a2 from excel:"+Dispatch.get(a2, "Value"));
          Variant f = new Variant(false);
          Dispatch.call(workbook, "Close", f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          xl.invoke("Quit", new Variant[] {});
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Are you running on a windows box or a unix/linux box ?

Answer (score 0):

I use it this way, but only to ExportAsPdfFormat

```
final String application = "Excel.Application";
            app = new ActiveXComponent(application);
            final ActiveXComponent workbooks = app.getPropertyAsComponent("Workbooks");
            app.setProperty("visible", false);
            app.setProperty("DisplayAlerts", false);
            app.setProperty("AutomationSecurity", 3);
            d = Dispatch.call(workbooks, "Open", this.getFileName(), ExcelConverter.UPDATELINKS, Variant.VT_FALSE, Variant.VT_MISSING, Variant.VT_MISSING, Variant.VT_MISSING, Variant.VT_TRUE).toDispatch();
            Dispatch.call(d, "ExportAsFixedFormat", ExcelConverter.XLTYPEPDF, this.getConvertedFileName(), ExcelConverter.XLQUALITYSTANDARD, Variant.VT_TRUE, Variant.VT_FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

im using Jacob lib version 1.18 and it needs to be initialized before anything else. It comes with two dll file each for different system version "jacob-1.18-x64.dll" and "jacob-1.18-x86.dll".

```
String libFile = System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("amd64") ? "/jacob-1.18-x64.dll" : "/jacob-1.18-x86.dll";

    /* Read DLL file*/

    InputStream inputStream = load_the_file_as_stream();
    /**
     *  Step 1: Create temporary file under <%user.home%>\AppData\Local\Temp\jacob.dll 
     *  Step 2: Write contents of `inputStream` to that temporary file.
     */
    File temporaryDll = File.createTempFile("jacob", ".dll");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(temporaryDll);
    byte[] array = new byte[8192];
    for (int i = inputStream.read(array); i != -1; i = inputStream.read(array)) {
        outputStream.write(array, 0, i);
    }
    outputStream.close();

    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, temporaryDll.getAbsolutePath());
    LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary();

    /* Temporary file will be removed after terminating-closing-ending the application-program */
    temporaryDll.deleteOnExit();
```